# Strange 150ms latency after hibernate session is opened

Tags: mysql, performance, hibernate, sessionfactory

i am using hibernate 3.6, hibernatetemplate, hibernateDaoSupport, opensessioninviewfilter and mysql db, i took a look at my query performance and i found that every query take more or less 300ms to execute after taking a look at the logs i found that there is a strange latency right after the hibernate session is opened :

18/09/12 01:23:59:721 DEBUG org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl - opened session at timestamp: 5521112431497216
18/09/12 01:23:59:884 DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - about to open PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0)

There is a gap of 160ms more or less after opening the session and opening the prepared statement, i don't have a guess of what is happening, i activated the connectionpool
the secondlevel cache but the queries are really fast is only this gap that is killing me,
i checked even if the sessionfactory is the same in everycall and it looks like to be the same, i even tried to pullout the opensessioinviewfilter.

Comment: Do you use Criteria API or HQL? Do you use named query or inline them in your code? Post it, it's very helpful to see. Try to activate PreparedStatement cache, it's about such properties while configuring connection/MySQL: cachePrepStmts, prepStmtCacheSize, prepStmtCacheSqlLimit. And then run the same query several times and see whether performace improved.

Comment: One critical information I think is missing is what you do with the session. Is it only a querying of data ( by identifier lookup or HQL) or you are saving or updating some entities too. Second - are there anymore debug statement in between the two you listed. If not probably you can activate debug level to TRACE to see what is happening in between.